# How can I link unlinked vertices?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

I am using Blender 2.77. I imported a .3ds of a snake to save time while exploring spline IK. Parenting to an armature fails and I suspect this is because the model's vertices are not all linked. I have attached a screen print. I hover over the verts and hit <kbd>L</kbd> and as you can see, not all of the verts are linked. When I select with <kbd>L</kbd> it should select all the verts. Is there a way to join them?

[image]

Comment: I did try that first thing. The mesh isn't in parts, except for the eyes and such so there aren't two sections to join. I don't know how to add the .blend to this post or I would so you could see it. I do have the link to the model I imported: http://archive3d.net/?a=download&id=2f591833

Comment: After more trial and error, I got it fixed. I converted all the tris to quads then removed the verts at the end of the first linked selection. Then after moving one edge loop close to the closest loop in the next section, I bridged the edge loop. When I tried this before I apparently didn't have the edge loops close enough so it wound up all wonky. This seemed to work. Now to see if it will parent to an armature correctly.

Comment: Anyway, what is failing is the "automatic weights" feature; if you set your weights manually everything works fine even with meshes that are "in parts"

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do it manually
first make sure the two unconnected meshes are close to each other

[image]

Select an edge loop from the first and second mesh where they should be connected

[image]

use the remove doubles operator and try different values of merge distance, make sure unselected option is unchecked

[image]